# Keyboard keys @ and " are switched

Tags: keyboard, keys

Keyboard keys <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> are switched after I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: run `setxkbmap -layout us` in teminal

Answer (score 2):

Pick the correct keyboard in "keyboards"

From these 2 characters you probably picked a US keyboard but have an English keyboard.

Open dash and search for keyboard. ALl of them have a layout in that program so you can quickly spot the one yours is.